# Fill / append rectangle on bottom of image c#

Tags: c#, image, drawing, fill

I need to fill an rectangle on bottom of my image, but not over the image, so it should be a kind of append a rectangle to bottom of image.

What I have for now:

```
    private void DrawRectangle()
    {
        string imageFilePath = @"c:\Test.jpg";
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            using (Image img = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath))
            {
                SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                int width = img.Width;
                int height = img.Height - 350;
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, height, width, 350);
            }
        }
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\Test1.jpg");
    }
```

But this is over the image.

Any idea's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the dimensions of your original image in order to set the size of the new bitmap, which must be larger to accommodate the rectangle.

```
private void DrawRectangle()
{
    string imageFilePath = @"c:\Test.jpg";
    int rectHeight = 100;

    using (Image img = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath)) // load original image
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height + rectHeight)) // create blank bitmap of desired size
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        // draw existing image onto new blank bitmap
        graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height); 
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        // draw your rectangle below the original image
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, img.Height, img.Width, rectHeight); 
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\Test1.bmp");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the `FillRectangle()` method overloads.. it has one with the following definition: `FillRectangle(Brush brush, int PositionX, int PositionY, int Width, int Height)`

your problem most likely stems on using an improper overload for what you're doing.